# How to open vscodium from terminal in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, ide, vscodium

I started to use VSCODIUM instead VSCODE cause i want to open source code from my workspace

VSCODIUM is good but i want to start it from terminal, or better, from my file manage "Dolphin"

I searched and o found that the step to start VSCODIUM from terminal is like VSCODE, then:

> `codium .`

but it does not work

Comment: Are you by chance using the flatpak version of Codium? If yes, you can start it with `flatpak run com.vscodium.codium`

Comment: Wow it works but i put a dot ahead of your command then it was "flatpak run com.vscodium.codium ." but is there a form a little bit more simplified?

Comment: You could add an alias to your bashrc file. To do that, you can add `alias codium="flatpak run com.vscodium.codium"` to ~/.bashrc. Then you can run `codium .` in the terminal and it should work as you expect. For more details you can read this article or any other article on the topic: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem, you can answer this question to me vote you and improve your reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/docs/index.md#terminal-support) of Codium.

In MacOS/Windows, go to VisualStudioCode and type CMD/crtl + p, then > and search for "Shell Command: Install 'codium' command in PATH", it will prompt for authorization to configure it within your system, authorize it and you're done.

For Linux, check out this:

> When the archive VSCodium-linux--.tar.gz is extracted, the main entry point for VSCodium is ./bin/codium.

then you should be able to create a shortcut (better called symlink) to link that command to a shorter command as 'codium'. You can find how to do it in this [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-symlink-in-linux).

Comment: Feb 2024, Macos 14.3.1, VSCodium 1.86.2
`shift + command + p` 
to reveal list of actions with  
__install codium in PATH__

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in latest version of VSCodium, you can directly use the command `codium`